# gTile for Unity?

Tags: unity, tiling

Im testing gnome shell for this Week now and the shell-extension gTile https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/ is a big advantage for gnome shell IMHO.

I want to switch back to Unity at the end of the week. Is there something similar to gTile for Unity?

I think its the first "Tiling-Manager" made for the masses. I would apreciate something like that for Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, i found out, that the grid plugin in ccsm can provide the aero-snap function with options for tiling to upper or lower corner left and right. so it can tile 4 windows onto one screen.

but its sill buggy (some pixels reach onto the next screen in dualview, no tiling with corners on the inside edge in dualview,...)

Answer (score 1):

more on k1l's answer:

CCSM is the Compiz Config Settings manager.  It's flaky and so not installed by default, but hit this link to install it: http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager

To bring up CCSM after it's install hit the Windows key, type "compiz" and return.  The Grid plugin is automatically installed and enabled, scroll down to see it.  One key is Control-Alt-5  (keypad 5), which makes the current window fullscreen.  Control-Alt-keypad-4 will move the window to fill the left half of the screen.